# pytest mark parametrization with dependency on each other

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, parametrized-testing

I'm using pytest for unittests and I would like to parametrize the tests.
I know I can use @pytest.mark.parametrize at class level and at method level.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", [1,2,3,4,5])
class TestXYZ:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param2", [6,7,8,9])
    def test_xyz(self, param1, param2):
        assert param1 == param2
```

However, in my case it happens that the param2 list depends on the actual param1 value.
I would like to obtain sth like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", [1,2,3,4,5])
class TestXYZ:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param2", getparams(param1))
    def test_xyz(self, param1, param2):
        assert param1 == param2
```

However, i could not figure out how to do it.

I tried to use nested functions, but this did'nt work out, too:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", [1,2,3,4,5])
class TestXYZ:
    def test_gen(self, param1):
        @pytest.mark.parametrize("param2", [6,7,8,9])
        def test_xyz(self, param1, param2):
            assert param1 == param2

        return test_gen
```

Pytest then just collect a testcase for param1.

Comment: I would recommend to look into how you can achieve your desired results by parametrizing fixtures.

Comment: Thank you, i'm trying out the fixture based solution, today. It already brought me forward with some testcases but not all. But it seems very promising.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```py
import pytest

parameter1 = [1, 2, 3]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("param1", parameter1)
class TestXYZ:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("param2", [4, 3, parameter1[0]])
    def test_xyz(self, param1, param2):
        assert param1 == param2
```

With output: `7 failed, 2 passed` for this example.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not answer my question. My problem was that the list of param2 values depends on the actual selected value for param1.